# What are the permutation matrices that satisfy $P^2 = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling to come up with a "general" answer to this question. I found a permutation matrix $$P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ where its square is equal to the identity matrix. But how would I generalize this?

Answer (score 2):

The proper question should be what permutations $\sigma$ satisfy $\sigma^2=1$. And the answer is those with $1$-cycles and $2$-cycles. Translating this into permutation matrices, the answer should be the matrices $P$ that are obtaine from the identity matrix by swapping some pairs of rows.

Comment: What do you mean by 1-cycles and 2-cycles? Also, would I say then that the only permutation matrices that satisfy the P^2 = I condition are pairwise row
exchange permutation matrices?

Comment: Well, you need to study some abstract algebra, see. e.g.  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation). Some pair of rows are swapped, while some others stay unchanged, typically. It could be that no pair of rows is exchanged, i.e. the identity matrix.

Comment: The idea isn't that hard. If $P^2=I$, for each $e_i$, then either $Pe_i=e_i$ or $Pe_i=e_j$, and then $Pe_j = P^2e_i = e_i$, hence $P$ swaps $e_i$ and $e_j$.

Comment: So would I that the only permutation matrices P which satisfy P^2 = I is the elementary matrix in which all rows have zeros and just a single 1.

Comment: @Enterbot This is not entirely correct. You could swap the first two rows of then the third and fourth rows without increasing the order. What matters is that none of the transpositions have a row in common.